# Why does a gas get hot when suddenly compressed? What is happening at the molecular level?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, ideal-gas, adiabatic

My guess is that the molecules of gas all have the same speed as before, but now there are much more collisions per unit area onto the thermometer, thus making the thermometer read a higher temperature. If this is so, then density is directly related to temperature when a substance experiences a change in density.

Is this the case?

Answer (score 21):

Because you are doing work to compress the gas, and the energy has to go somewhere. The molecules speed up because they collide with the wall moving forward--- if you move a wall forward, a ball which bounces off the wall reflects going faster by twice the speed of the wall, because if you move along with the wall, it reflects at the same speed.

#### Answers to comment questions

- After the gas cools off, the gas molecules are moving at the same speed as before.
- The second question is a form of Maxwell demon. If you know when the molecular collisions come with such precision that you can move the wall when the molecules will not bounce, you can compress the gas without doing any work. But in order to do this, you must get and store the information about where all the molecules are, a process which requires a huge amount of entropy production. The information about the molecules allows you to reduce their volume without increasing their energy.
- In any situation where classical mechanics works, for kinetic energy of gasses in particular, the temperature is just the same as the average molecular kinetic energy. For all nonrelativistic systems, the average kinetic energy in each atom is $3T\over 2$ in Boltzmann units (k=1). This is a special case of the equipartition law--- every quadratic degree of freedom gets ${kT\over 2}$ energy in equilibrium. Because of the relation between temperature and kinetic energy, the speeds of molecules in two gasses at the same temperature are the same. So after the gas comes to equilibrium with the surroundings, it has the same average speed for the molecules independent of its volume (this is a molecular kinetic-energy potential-energy separation theorem, which is even true when the material liquifies or solidifies, at least at room temperature  where normal solids obey the Dulong Petit law).

#### Entropy increase

There is a second way to understand the temperature increase. When you squeeze the gas, you are increasing your knowledge of where the molecules are, you are decreasing their wandering volume. This means that, if nothing else happens, you decrease their entropy. So something must have happened to make you know less about the state of the universe. If they are not allowed to dump heat and entropy into the exterior universe, the only thing that can happen is that they move faster, increasing your uncertainty about how fast they are going.

The decrease in entropy with a decrease in volume from $V_i$ to $V_f$ is

$$ N\log({V_f\over V_i}) $$

This is intuitive--- the logarithm of the number of configuration is the log of $V^N$ (ignoring an N! denominator from indistinguishable particles.

The increase in entropy from a change in temperature from $T_i$ to $T_f$ is given by

$$ NC_V \log({T_f\over T_i}) $$

Where $C_v$ is the rate of entropy increase per unit temperature. So that the relation that the entropy is constant gives the adiabatic expansion law: $V\over T^{C_v}$ is constant, that is, the ratio of absolute temperatures before and after is a certain power of the ratio of the volumes after and before.

I should point out that if you move the piston extremely quickly, at comparable to the speed of sound of the gas, you will produce *extra* heat in addition to the minimum necessary to ensure the entropy doesn't go down. The extra heat can be understood in two equivalent ways:

- you are overcompressing a thin skin of gas near the piston, that momentarily exerts a greater back-pressure on the piston than the gas would normally if you did things slowly. So you are doing more work to compress the gas quickly.
- You are learning more about the positions of the molecules from the slow rate of pressure relaxation--- you know that a large fraction of the volume of the gas is mushed near the piston.

This is a classical more-you-know less-you-know statement, that the more precisely you know where the molecules in a gas are, the less precisely you know how fast they are moving (the hotter the gas gets), at constant information (entropy). This is *not* the Heisenberg uncertainty principle, it is just classical thermodyanamics, and here the knowledge interpretation is exact, because the entropy is a measure of classical knowledge you have about the microstate. The quantum mechanical uncertainty principle is not a statement of ignorance about hidden variables, at least not in any obvious way, so it doesn't have a precise informational interpretation like this does.

Comment: Ok, so question: once the system has cooled off in temperature and reached equilibrium with the surroundings, is the average speed of each molecule the same as it was before being compressed?

Comment: Also, lets imagine that the wall only moves when there are no collisions happening, and that the wall stops for an instant when a ball needs to bounce off it, thus not changing the speed of the ball which loses no energy to the collision. So, now, the volume is small and all the balls have the same speed as before. Now, lets imagine we allow for energy to be lost to collisions. This is where I imagine that the increased temperature comes from because now more balls hit the wall, releasing energy at a higher rate due to more collisions than before. Is this the case?

Comment: I think this merits an entirely different question: Do gas molecules in a bigger volume with move at the same speed as gas molecules of the same type in a smaller volume when both volumes have the same temperature?

Comment: First of all I believe that you cant say that the heat has been transferred to the gas molecules because of your work done on the piston, that work is translated into the movement of the piston and that's that. Now if you are saying that the temperature of the 2 volumes are the same then what is your original question?! There is no temperature change! Therefore the gas does not get hot.

Comment: @truskr: I expanded the answer.

Comment: What is the downvote about?

Comment: @Adir: The heat has been transferred to the gas through the piston. The piston starts out stopped and ends stopped--- where did the energy go? I believe you have the impression that this is like a spring, which can store potential energy. But the gas is not like a spring, it stores internal energy in molecular motions only, not in internal fields. There is no confusion on this point, and I don't understand why you assert something blatently wrong with complete confidence.

Comment: @AdirPeretz I say the temperatures are the same, but I also said we have allowed the new volume to reach thermal equilibrium. The higher temperature is experienced before thermal equlibrium is reached.

Comment: @RonMaimon Wow, very interesting! I'm still confused though. I keep imagining that since there are more molecules per unit volume after compression (higher density of molecules) that there will be more molecules hitting the thermometer and that even though they have the same speed after reaching equilibrium, they will transfer more energy to the thermometer because there is a higher number collisions to the thermometer. Why is my thinking in that case wrong? Is there something I'm overlooking?

Comment: @truskr: you are missing that the molecules also take away energy from the thermometer--- equilbrium is established when the thermometer atoms are jiggling at the same average speeds as the gas atoms (classically, quantum mechanically, some motions can disappear).

Comment: Its so hard to visualize. To me it seems that in order for the particles of the thermometer to move at the same average speed, the gas particles would have to be slower if they are more concentrated, although I know you are saying this doesn't happen. SO what happens if you put a mercury thermometer inside a vacuum (the vacuum is in a room at room temperature, but the thermometer floats magically inside the vacuum without contacting to the outter surroundings of the vacuum)? What will its temperature read after equlibrium (assuming no radiation hits it)?

Comment: @truskr: if it can't equilibrate by exchaning heat, it will just jiggle with whatever temperature it started with. The reason you are confused is because you are missing that the exchange of energy is completely statistical, so that if an atom has more kinetic energy than its neighbors, its kinetic energy will leave, and if it has less kinetic energy, it will absorb the energy. The energy economics is by the Boltzmann distribution, it is maximum entropy at a fixed energy. This is a subtle universal law, the law of statistical thermal equilibrium, and took decades to fully appreciate.

Comment: @Ron Maimon Thank you for the detailed answer. But I am confused about one thing, specifically with your theory of the increase in ball speed due to the moving wall. Let's assume the gas sample is insulated so the compression process is adiabatic. Now imagine the compression is done very, very slowly. So the wall's velocity is approximately 0, and the balls or molecules that collide with the wall has negligible change in speed. However, despite the compression being slow, the same work is done, and the final result is the same (temperature increases).How is this explained then microscopically?

Comment: @user4624937: Slow or fast, the gain in energy from the collisions is the same, it is the total work done against the pressure. I was assuming it is adiabatic already.

Comment: @RonMaimon I agree the total work done is same whether the wall is moving slow or fast. But microscopically how could the balls increase in speed, if the wall's velocity is almost zero? A ball wouldn't get faster after bouncing off the wall.

Comment: @user462437: Each ball would get a smaller increase in  speed, and the process of moving the wall in would take longer, the net result is the same (obviously, but work it out if it is confusing).

Answer (score 0):

temperature is the measure of speed of molecules. when you compress the gas molecules start moving faster, which is the same as saying the temperature increases.

why do molecules start moving faster? there are many ways of explaining this. here's one. when molecules are squeezed into a smaller volume their location is now more certain, it's locked in a smaller space. we seem to get more order and less chaos? this should come at a price, and it does: the molecules resist to being ordered. so they pay back by moving faster. so, in the end there no more order than it was before. the nature resists order.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why a gas heats up when it is compressed into a smaller space, is because the ambient heat that the gas possessed in its original volume, has now been confined to a smaller volume—same amount of heat but now more concentrated—the temperature goes up. When the vessel storing the newly compressed gas cools off to the ambient temperature of its environment, energy in the form of heat is lost to the environment. If the air is now released into the atmosphere, it expands from its compressed state to resume the volume that it previously occupied—except that it can't because it has lost energy. In order for the gas to occupy its original volume, it requires heat from the surrounding environment—which may include your hand, which is why the expanding gas feels cool—it's sucking heat energy from your body.

Answer (score -1):

The gas gets hotter because the energy has no where to go and it must convert into heat. The molecules bounce back and forth with one another creating more and more energy and less space, so the molecules began to compress through the helical rotors.

Comment: Is energy "created"?